# When I import a new csv file for Machine-Learning analysis. How to get the table structure?

Tags: dolphindb

When I import a new csv file for Machine-Learning analysis. How to get the table structure?

If it’s a wide table, it’s inefficiency to input a csv file manually. Is there an efficient way to do this job?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the function “extractTextSchema()” to get the structure of the table.